# Concavity of ratio of modified Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

In studying the solution to a coupled second order ODE, I noticed, based on numerics, that the equation

$$K_0(x) - bK_0(ax) = 0$$

where $a, b > 1$ appears to only have one solution for $x > 0$. Since the ratio

$$\frac{K_0(x)}{K_0(ax)}$$

seems to be strictly monotonically increasing (which would prove that there is only one solution), I wanted to show that the derivative of this ratio is positive. This leads to showing that

$$a\frac{K_0(x)}{K_1(x)} - \frac{K_0(ax)}{K_1(ax)} > 0$$

which would be true if the function

$$\frac{K_0(x)}{K_1(x)}$$

converges to $0$ as $x \to 0$ and is concave. Both conditions appear to be true numerically. I can probably prove the first condition using asymptotics, but I'm stumped on the second condition. It appears that the ratio of Bessel functions is a well-studied subject, but so far I haven't found anything regarding the concavity of the ratio of these two Bessel functions. Alternatively one can just show directly that the function is subadditive (I think subadditivity is a weaker condition), but I also didn't find anything about that. The closest I can find is conjecture 2 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2022-150-07/S0002-9939-2022-15891-2/S0002-9939-2022-15891-2.pdf), but that conjecture is stronger than what I need, so I'm hoping there is some other weaker results out there that shows it.

Does anyone know of some good resources/has an idea how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

For $0 \leq x \leq \frac 15$ $$\frac{K_0(x)}{K_1(x)}=- (\log (x)+\gamma -\log (2))x+O\left(x^3\right)$$ is a decent approximation.

Comment: How does that prove that $K_0/K_1$ is concave?

Comment: @neuro630. At least close to $x=0$